# How to store a value in nested collection field in blueprism?

Tags: blueprism

I need to store "x" in Item Data.Equipment Requirement.Tariff.0

Item Data is a collection which has a field of type collection "Equipment Requirement"
Equipment Requirement is a collection which has a field Tariff and filled with 6 rows.

I am sure that there is no naming errors, but each time i store something in Item Data.Equipment Requirement.Tariff.0 i got and error:

> Internal : Could not store calculation result - Field Item
>   Data.Equipment Requirement.Tariff.0 not found

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Blue Prism's dot notation only has the capability to refer to collection fields, not specific row indices. Use the `Utility - Collection Manipulation` VBO's `Set Collection Field` Action:

```
Business Object: Utility - Collection Manipulation
Action: Set Collection Field
Inputs:
    - Row Index: 0
    - Collection: Item Data.Equipment Requirement
    - Field Name: Tariff
    - Value: "35"
Outputs:
    - Updated Collection: Item Data.Equipment Requirement
```

Comment: Hi esqew, Any idea how I would 'Add Row' in a nested collection? Sorry to pop the question here but from work, I am unable to provide any screen prints so just thought I'd ask here. Everytime I try to add a row (collection reference as: **Main.BusinessFacts**.. **Main** being the main collection and **BusinessFacts** is the nested collection in **Main**), it says collection not found

Comment: @Zac This isn't related to the original question being asked or the answer - please feel free to use the "Ask Question" button to create a separate question for this issue.